# Still getting exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, ssl, https, self-signed, httpsurlconnection

My certificate details are below

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        0b:28:94:71:ae:86:c5:13:54:61:02:64:cc:f0:68:6e:15:86:86:07
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C = IN, ST = Kerala, L = Cochin, O = Vuelogix Technologies Pvt Ltd., OU = IT/Software, CN = 192.168.0.129, emailAddress = sanooj.m@vuelogix.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Nov 16 08:52:51 2018 GMT
        Not After : Nov 16 08:52:51 2019 GMT
    Subject: C = IN, ST = Kerala, L = Cochin, O = Vuelogix Technologies Pvt Ltd., OU = IT/Software, CN = 192.168.0.129, emailAddress = sanooj.m@vuelogix.com
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:c6:5e:2f:db:a6:04:25:d5:c7:d5:2d:df:4f:7f:
                91:42:0f:7e:aa:75:bc:59:2f:c5:26:a3:e7:7d:de:
                cc:a6:93:a8:d3:a9:6e:69:a9:b2:1a:43:9f:f4:03:
                31:a8:9d:fe:58:b0:fa:55:2c:31:3e:13:32:78:43:
                1b:18:1d:0f:13:32:40:fa:c1:4f:eb:e9:b1:e4:e3:
                3c:06:33:b0:98:9e:e7:fd:67:cb:3b:ef:8c:c1:68:
                e4:2f:10:c3:52:97:11:3d:e2:8a:b3:d3:d5:bd:15:
                f0:94:df:3b:28:d1:11:68:b6:6e:e6:4a:06:5c:36:
                aa:a2:e5:3d:e8:41:99:57:96:e0:41:49:f7:46:20:
                fd:84:9e:a0:55:6f:24:84:f1:06:a4:c5:f9:f0:9f:
                63:03:a2:be:f1:78:80:2c:a5:9f:81:3e:dc:32:5c:
                b9:c1:17:b0:f2:af:fb:0f:b1:33:ff:f5:4b:ad:a8:
                68:b9:20:17:21:ca:c8:dd:c3:cb:a2:ce:2a:ca:d3:
                ee:67:98:cd:08:ca:7e:50:e8:26:18:a3:ac:3c:5b:
                f9:26:7a:41:14:56:05:c3:63:24:d6:e5:0f:6c:93:
                b3:ce:ed:7e:94:a0:36:f3:d4:7c:84:63:f3:c4:4c:
                71:06:3a:e8:6b:9e:e8:82:2c:bb:0a:23:11:d6:dd:
                4d:c9
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            38:BF:E5:C9:8C:5F:27:12:0A:BE:66:FA:6D:A0:F7:63:28:84:67:00
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:38:BF:E5:C9:8C:5F:27:12:0A:BE:66:FA:6D:A0:F7:63:28:84:67:00

        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     39:93:cf:23:79:ee:99:a2:fc:39:51:78:e6:e9:1d:83:7e:61:
     6b:1b:21:d4:80:6b:4f:96:84:5d:d9:2c:39:7b:b8:69:c6:d4:
     90:5b:93:41:4e:ed:04:8c:ad:54:d9:fd:39:3d:52:d3:6f:58:
     29:7b:4d:9a:9e:ab:9f:03:64:ae:e3:ab:2a:c9:0c:c4:ce:15:
     22:c3:19:65:27:df:55:10:32:ea:c8:fa:1c:d1:43:74:88:79:
     1b:2a:bc:fb:a6:0f:0f:48:ac:33:6d:e2:15:a6:48:31:6e:56:
     d8:32:13:e6:32:93:48:a9:46:cb:de:8d:06:dd:a9:5d:80:c8:
     2d:9c:7a:7c:ac:8e:d0:d9:da:ba:ed:3c:89:27:ec:6b:05:c0:
     c5:33:a6:5c:e4:19:e8:6a:67:84:3d:25:34:65:f7:b8:2a:0b:
     75:59:65:7c:60:c8:35:98:ac:a1:78:54:0c:00:f7:46:0b:1c:
     05:92:73:dd:6a:76:98:ac:b9:91:85:31:83:c4:de:b7:c1:09:
     c5:99:8b:bc:a3:16:10:a4:d5:ae:4b:03:8b:a5:18:e5:59:39:
     e0:15:8e:99:ef:52:cc:de:00:80:06:33:70:8d:54:c5:80:25:
     6a:5e:c9:4b:38:00:5e:fa:02:41:ac:44:52:2d:e0:40:6a:86:
     30:91:cc:c9
```

And I'm trying to make an HttpsURLConnection to the following URL
"https://192.168.0.129:8443/ferno-webapp/user-notifications/remove-expired"

Both IPs are same , but I'm still getting this exception .
I can hit the above URL in browser but can't make an HttpsURLConnection from code.

I'hv generated tried a certificate with the port(8443) also but nothing works

Please anyone help me.

Comment: You created a self signed certificate, and you did not add a SAN (Subject Alternative Name) extension which is what the error message tells you. You need to generate a new proper certificate and until that you will always get an error, so it is not a configuration problem. Modern browsers, per CAB Forum requirements, mandates the SAN extension.

Comment: thanks @PatrickMevzek . can u please tell me how to add a SAN . I have followed so many tutorials but didn't get a proper solution. Is there any link which explains how to create a self signed certificate with SAN.?

Thanks.

Comment: You can find many options here to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl but my prefered one is https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327262/6368697 ; it is even simpler if you have OpenSSL 1.1.1 because then you have the `-addext` option.